# Excel: Partial match any content in column B with full content in column A & return yes or no

Tags: excel, match, partial

I have two columns I would like to compare. Column A (which has the full nam and column B has an abbreviated name. In column C I would like to take the value of each cell in column A and do a partial match on all values in column B and then return a "Yes" or "No" value. The most common formula I seem to be able to find down this track is this;

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A3&"*",B:B,1,0)),"No","Yes")
```

However this is partial matching column A to all of column B, which is the opposite to what I am looking for. Example;

```
Column A        Column B      Column C
UserData_123    UserData      Yes 
CompData_321    FooData       No
```

A1 returns true as Column B has UserData.
A2 returns false as Column B has no match for CompData_321

Feels like I am really not seeing the forest for the trees here. Any tips?

Comment: If it were working the way you wanted, what would you expect for output in `Column C`?  Using an example where you get undesired output with your approach might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If all the names in column A are separated by the underscore, you can use the text to columns feature under the data tab, which will strip the numbers off the names and allow you to compare just the letters.